# Select node, which contains descendants with specific attribute

Tags: xpath

I have similiar structure to:

```
<tr>
    <td>I WANT THIS</td>
    <td>
        <a class="unread">text</a>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <a class="read">text</a>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

And I need to select `<tr>` node, which have `<a>` node with attribute `[@class='unread']`, to select inner `<td>` later.

I tried `//tr[a/@class='unread']` and `//tr/a[@class='textMsg unread']` but didn't work. How can I get my `<tr>` node?

Answer (score 10):

`a` tag is not a child of `tr` tag, you can try this xpath:

```
//tr[.//a/@class='unread']
```

Or

```
//tr[descendant::a/@class='unread']
```

Comment: The first seems works. Thanks.
Is here a way, how can I get directly my `<td>`?

Answer (score 1):

**To select the wanted `td` element(s), use**:

```
//tr//td[.//a[@class = 'unread']]
```

**If it is known that the `td` is a child of the `tr` and the `a` is a child of the `td`, the above may be simplified to**:

```
//tr/td[a[@class = 'unread']]
```